# (LINUX)Porting from Qt4 to QT5 undefined symbol : _Zn9Qwidget11stylechangeER6QStyle

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I ported my application from qt 4.8.0 to qt 5.5.1
It compiled without any error but at run time the application crashes and get the message undefined symbol : _Zn9Qwidget11stylechangeER6QStyle in one of my .so file linked dynamically.

When searched couldn't find any function styleChange() in whole project source code.

Cleaned project, deleted all intermediate files, all object files, .so file but same result.
It seemed it is a qt4.8.0 function but could'nt find and hence not able to debug.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the name of the undefined symbol? `c++filt _Zn9Qwidget11stylechangeER6QStyle` doesn't produce a demangled.name.

Answer (score 0):

> When searched couldn't find any function styleChange() in whole project source code.

Note that in the mangled name 'c' is in lowercase: `stylechange`. Have you tried to search for this method?

Comment: Looks like a homebrew class on top of some std Qt, probably the QWidget itself. This may be wrong impression of course.